# Event handling checkbox - jQuery icheck plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

It look simple and straight forward, but I am unable to manage simple click on the check box.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkfront[]" class="front-checkbox">
```

jQuery

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("triggered1");
    $(".front-checkbox").click(function() {
        alert("triggered");
    });
});
```

**But it is not working at all, neither it is showing error. I am stuck.**

When I try with:

```
<a class="front-checkbox" href="javascript:void(0)">dd</a>
```

**it is working .. why it is misbehaving with checkbox?**

On inspecting check box I found following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkfront" class="front-checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
```

**I doubt checkbox is generating div and event is triggered there.**

Comment: you have wrapped the code inside document.ready()??

Comment: Its perfectly fine... what errors it is showing?

Comment: its working see here  http://jsfiddle.net/8q8o5rmw/

Comment: its also working see here  http://jsfiddle.net/8q8o5rmw/1/

Comment: In some browsers, the click trigger is not functioning. Use `change` trigger instead.

Answer (score 1):

I managed it somehow from icheck documentation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.front-checkbox').on('ifChecked', function(event){
         alert('xx');
     });
  });
```

for more  http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `change` event for checkbox, not `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".front-checkbox").change(function() {
        if(this.checked)
         alert("checked");
        else
         alert("unchecked");
    });
});
```

and if the **HTML** is generated dynamically after DOM load then use **delegated event:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("change",".front-checkbox",function() {
            if(this.checked)
             alert("checked");
            else
             alert("unchecked");
        });
    });
```

Comment: your html seems correct, it should work can you reproduce problem in fiddle?